# What's preventing my php on Leopard (10.5) from running?

Tags: osx-leopard, apache-http-server, php5

I have an old mini running a vanilla Leopard install that I use to host low-volume sites as I learn web dev. I have successfully set up virtual hosts and they are running static placeholder sites. In full disclosure, one of my sites is my first Rails app running Fusion Passenger successfully.

I'd like to set up one of my placeholder sites to be a WordPress site so that means enabling the stock PHP stack. Following several tutorials, I have uncommented the line to load the php module and restarted the web server. I put in the

```
 <?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

line into a file in a public facing directory and apache is passing this through as text only. No other Googling points to what else I have overlooked and why I'm posting here as a reality check. I appear to have installed mysql via homebrew successfully. Because this is an older machine with a small amount of RAM I'm trying to keep it lean which is why I'm resistant to adding the overhead of MAMP to it.

What am I overlooking? thanx, sam

Comment: Ensure your file ends with an apache/php recognised extension, like ".php"

Comment: Yes. [http://powerhat.org/btest.php](http://powerhat.org/btest.php) Thx for closing the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digging further on Google, it appears there is more to do on 10.5 than others indicate. A user on php.net (sachin at dharmapurikar) commented on an older answer of this that fills in the missing piece:

Add this to httpd.conf:

```
 <IfModule mod_php5.c>
   # If php is turned on, we respect .php and .phps files.
   AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
   AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps

   # Since most users will want index.php to work we also automatically enable index.php
   <IfModule mod_dir.c>
     DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
   </IfModule>
 </IfModule>
```